# Rename underlying table without breaking dashboards in Metabase

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, metabase

We want to rename a table that is used in Metabase in the underlying database. Several dashboards depend on this table. Can we rename the underlying table and then ensure that the dashboards still work?

Comment: Which database are you connecting to?

Comment: In this case it is a Snowflake Datawarehouse. Metabase itself is running on MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The quick way

By using a view in Snowflake, you should be able to rename the old table, while still allowing queries on the old name to still work.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ SECURE ] [ RECURSIVE ] VIEW [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name>
    [ ( <column_list> ) ]
    [ COPY GRANTS ]
    [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
    AS <select_statement>
```

This would look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW old_name AS select * from new_name;
```

## The long way

By querying the report_card table within the Metabase database, you can find the question numbers of all the questions that use the table, and then change the name in them.

```
SELECT * from report_card where dataset_query like '%old_table%'
```

You could automatically change the table name, but this would risk accidentally changing names that are similar or other breaking changes.